# How to apply filters to previously recorded sound and save modified version using AudioKit?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, audio-processing, audiokit

There is a previously recorded sound file containing user's voice. What I need to do is apply some sound filter to change the voice and after that be able to save and play modified version.

**AudioKit** can open file using `[[AKFileInput alloc] initWithFilename:file1];` and save with `[[AKManager sharedManager] renderToFile:outputFile forDuration:duration];`

Any ideas how to apply some effects between these 2 commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to opening the file with AKFileInput, you have to play it back, and to do so, you'll be creating an AKInstrument.  In that AKInstrument you can process the output with any of AudioKit's signal modifier operations.

Comment: The thing is that I need to apply filter to file without playing it.

Comment: @YakivKovalsky That problem is solved in iOS 11, I'm told.