# How to apply audio effect to a file and write to filesystem - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, audio, avfoundation, audiokit

I'm building an app that should allow user to apply audio filters to a recorded audio, such as Reverb, Boost.

I was unable to find any viable source of information on how to apply filters to a file itself, because it's needed to upload processed file to server later.

I'm currently using AudioKit for visualization, and I'm aware that it's capable of doing audio processing, but only for playback. Please give any suggestions for further research.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply filters to previously recorded sound and save modified version using AudioKit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32714320/how-to-apply-filters-to-previously-recorded-sound-and-save-modified-version-usin)

Answer (score 9):

AudioKit has an offline render node that doesn't require iOS 11. Here's an example, the player.schedule(...) and player.start(at.) bits are required as AKAudioPlayer's underlying AVAudioPlayerNode will block on the calling thread waiting for the next render if you start it with `player.play()`.

```
import UIKit
import AudioKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var player: AKAudioPlayer?
    var reverb = AKReverb()
    var boost = AKBooster()
    var offlineRender = AKOfflineRenderNode()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "theFunkiestFunkingFunk", withExtension: "mp3") else {
            return
        }
        var audioFile: AKAudioFile?
        do {
            audioFile = try AKAudioFile.init(forReading: url)
            player = try AKAudioPlayer.init(file: audioFile!)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        guard let player = player else {
            return
        }


        player >>> reverb >>> boost >>> offlineRender

        AudioKit.output = offlineRender
        AudioKit.start()


        let docs = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        let dstURL = docs.appendingPathComponent("rendered.caf")

        offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = false
        player.schedule(from: 0, to: player.duration, avTime: nil)
        let sampleTimeZero = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: 0, atRate: AudioKit.format.sampleRate)
        player.play(at: sampleTimeZero)
        do {
            try offlineRender.renderToURL(dstURL, seconds: player.duration)
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return
        }
        offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = true

        print("Done! Rendered to " + dstURL.path)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey Dave, I'm trying AudioKit 4.0 that seems to have offline rendering (https://audiokitpro.com/audiokit-4-released/), but seems that AudioKit.mainMixer is not available, so I tried 
`player >>> reverb >>> boost >>> offlineRender >>> **AudioKit.engine.mainMixerNode**`, and it's not working. It generates an audio of the same length, but only silent.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, the AudioKit.mainMixer was never merged.  I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I just tried again, and it's working, but what should I do to avoid playing it? If I remove player.play() the file is empty again. Also, I tried player.pause() immediately after play() and it crashes.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: After you perform the render to url, and before you set offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled to true, stop the player.  When you set offlineRender.internalRenderEnabled = true, you are basically resuming normal rendering.

Comment: Worked great! Thanks Dave!

Comment: This answer is wrong right now with AudioKit 4.0.4 version - it now uses AudioKit.renderToFile and works on iOS 11+ only

Comment: You're partially right.  This method is still necessary for < iOS 11.  You should provide an answer with the iOS 11+ AudioKit.renderToFile method :)

Answer (score 7):

You can use the newly-introduced "manual rendering" features from Audio Unit plugins (see example below).

If you need to support older macOS/iOS version, I would be surprised if you can't achieve the same with *AudioKit* (even though I haven't tried it myself). For instance, using an `AKSamplePlayer` as your first node (which will read your audio file), then building and connecting your effects and using an `AKNodeRecorder` as your last node.

#### Example of manual rendering using the new audio unit features

```
import AVFoundation

//: ## Source File
//: Open the audio file to process
let sourceFile: AVAudioFile
let format: AVAudioFormat
do {
    let sourceFileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "mixLoop", withExtension: "caf")!
    sourceFile = try AVAudioFile(forReading: sourceFileURL)
    format = sourceFile.processingFormat
} catch {
    fatalError("could not open source audio file, \(error)")
}

//: ## Engine Setup
//:    player -> reverb -> mainMixer -> output
//: ### Create and configure the engine and its nodes
let engine = AVAudioEngine()
let player = AVAudioPlayerNode()
let reverb = AVAudioUnitReverb()

engine.attach(player)
engine.attach(reverb)

// set desired reverb parameters
reverb.loadFactoryPreset(.mediumHall)
reverb.wetDryMix = 50

// make connections
engine.connect(player, to: reverb, format: format)
engine.connect(reverb, to: engine.mainMixerNode, format: format)

// schedule source file
player.scheduleFile(sourceFile, at: nil)
//: ### Enable offline manual rendering mode
do {
    let maxNumberOfFrames: AVAudioFrameCount = 4096 // maximum number of frames the engine will be asked to render in any single render call
    try engine.enableManualRenderingMode(.offline, format: format, maximumFrameCount: maxNumberOfFrames)
} catch {
    fatalError("could not enable manual rendering mode, \(error)")
}
//: ### Start the engine and player
do {
    try engine.start()
    player.play()
} catch {
    fatalError("could not start engine, \(error)")
}
//: ## Offline Render
//: ### Create an output buffer and an output file
//: Output buffer format must be same as engine's manual rendering output format
let outputFile: AVAudioFile
do {
    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0]
    let outputURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentsPath + "/mixLoopProcessed.caf")
    outputFile = try AVAudioFile(forWriting: outputURL, settings: sourceFile.fileFormat.settings)
} catch {
    fatalError("could not open output audio file, \(error)")
}

// buffer to which the engine will render the processed data
let buffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(pcmFormat: engine.manualRenderingFormat, frameCapacity: engine.manualRenderingMaximumFrameCount)!
//: ### Render loop
//: Pull the engine for desired number of frames, write the output to the destination file
while engine.manualRenderingSampleTime < sourceFile.length {
    do {
        let framesToRender = min(buffer.frameCapacity, AVAudioFrameCount(sourceFile.length - engine.manualRenderingSampleTime))
        let status = try engine.renderOffline(framesToRender, to: buffer)
        switch status {
        case .success:
            // data rendered successfully
            try outputFile.write(from: buffer)

        case .insufficientDataFromInputNode:
            // applicable only if using the input node as one of the sources
            break

        case .cannotDoInCurrentContext:
            // engine could not render in the current render call, retry in next iteration
            break

        case .error:
            // error occurred while rendering
            fatalError("render failed")
        }
    } catch {
        fatalError("render failed, \(error)")
    }
}

player.stop()
engine.stop()

print("Output \(outputFile.url)")
print("AVAudioEngine offline rendering completed")
```

You can find more docs and examples about the updates to the AudioUnit format [there](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/501/).

Comment: The problem is, though, that you cannot process a file using AudioEngine without _playing_ it.

Comment: That must be new in iOS 11, then. And about time. Thanks!

Comment: @matt Yep, that's new to iOS 11/macOS High Sierra. You can watch the corresponding WWDC at https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/501/ (the part about offline manual rendering starts around 8 minutes and ends around 15)