# AKOfflineRenderNode - Scheduling AKAudioPlayers, only the last player renders

Tags: swift, audiokit

Getting some weird results when trying to render a sequence of AKAudioPlayers with AudioKit 4.0, Swift 4 on iOS 11.1

I'm aware of AudioKit.renderToFile alternative on the development branch (https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/09aedf7c119a399ab00026ddfb91ae6778570176) but would like to cover iOS 9+ if possible

**Expected result:**
A long audio file with the each file (URL) rendered in sequence

**Actual result:**
Only the last scheduled file is rendered (at the correct offset in the resulting wav file)

Weirdly, if I schedule them all at the 0 offset, they all get rendered. Also, if I play things back without rendering, it sounds correct (though I have to adjust the AVAudioTime to use mach_absolute_time)

It almost seems like scheduling an AKAudioPlayer cancels the previous one.

Setup:

```
  class func initialize (){

    // .... 

    do {
         try AKSettings.setSession(category: .playAndRecord, with: .allowBluetoothA2DP)
     } catch {
         AKLog("Could not set session category.")
     }
     //AKSettings.playbackWhileMuted = true
     AKSettings.defaultToSpeaker = true

     mainMixer = AKMixer()
     offlineRender = AKOfflineRenderNode()

     mainMixer! >>> offlineRender!
     AudioKit.output = offlineRender!
     AudioKit.start()

     // ....
```

Rendering:

```
class func testRender(urls: [URL], dest: URL, offset: TimeInterval = 2){

      // Stop / Start AudioKit when switching internalRenderEnabled, otherwise I get the following error:
      // *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'player started when engine not running' 

     AudioKit.stop()

     var players = [AKAudioPlayer]()
     var scheduleTime : TimeInterval = 0

     // create players
     for url in urls {
         do {
             let file = try AKAudioFile(forReading: url)
             let player = try AKAudioPlayer(file: file)
             players.append(player)
             player.connect(to: mainMixer!)
             print("Connecting player")
         } catch {
             print("error reading")
         }

     }


     offlineRender!.internalRenderEnabled = false
     AudioKit.start()

     for player in players{
         do {
             //  0 instead of mach_absolute_time(), otherwise the result is silent
             let avTime = AKAudioPlayer.secondsToAVAudioTime(hostTime: 0, time: scheduleTime)
             // schedule and play according to:
             // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45799686/how-to-apply-audio-effect-to-a-file-and-write-to-filesystem-ios/45807586#45807586
             player.schedule(from: 0, to: player.duration, avTime: nil)
             player.play(at: avTime);
             scheduleTime += offset
         } catch {
              print("error reading")
         }

     }

     // add some padding
     scheduleTime += 3

     let duration = scheduleTime
     do {
         try offlineRender!.renderToURL(dest, seconds: duration)

     } catch {
         print("error rendering")
     }

     // cleanup
     players.forEach { $0.schedule(from: 0, to: $0.duration, avTime: nil)}
     players.forEach({$0.stop()})
     players.forEach({$0.disconnectOutput()})

     offlineRender!.internalRenderEnabled = true


 }
```

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Reading https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/commit/09aedf7c119a399ab00026ddfb91ae6778570176 it sounds like the OfflineRenderer was depricated since it's not working post iOS11. Sounds like there's no plan of fixing but to deprecate in favor of a iOS11+ only solution?

Answer (score 3):

AKOfflineRenderNode has been deprecated as of iOS 11.0.  Version 4.0.4 has an AudioKit.renderToFile method to replace it.  It was updated recently (in late 2017).

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like the AKOFflineRednerNode is indeed deprecated in the coming versions of AudioKit and is not working on iOS11. Reading comments discussing the issue on GitHub it sounds like the plan is to encapsulate both the new (iOS11+) offline rendering and the old (iOS9-10) under a common interface (AudioKit.renderToFile). However for now it seems to be iOS11 only.

After some testing with the dev version (install instructions here: https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit/blob/master/Frameworks/README.md) I got the following code to work as intended:

```
try AudioKit.renderToFile(outputFile, seconds: duration, prerender: {
    var scheduleTime : TimeInterval = 0
   for player in players{
        let dspTime = AVAudioTime(sampleTime: AVAudioFramePosition(scheduleTime * AKSettings.sampleRate), atRate: AKSettings.sampleRate)

        player.play(at: dspTime)
        scheduleTime += offset
    }
})
```

Unless someone can provide a workaround that gets the OfflineRenderNode working on iOS11 and until the official release of AudioKit with the renderToFile implemented this is the best answer I could find.