# iOS: Process audio from AVPlayer video track

Tags: ios, video, avplayer, audiounit, audiokit

I plan to refactor my recording system in My iOS app.
Context:
Up to now, I record video and audio separately, starting recording both approximatly at same time. Once record is finished, same system, I play the video and audio separately, applying AudioUnits on the fly on audio. Finally, I merge the video and modified audio.
It happens that both records don't start at the same time (for any reasons), producing an unsynchronized result.

Would it be possible to refactor my system like this:

```
1) Record normal video with audio into mov file --> I would be sure that audio+video would be synchronized.

2) During viewing the result with AVPlayer, process the audio part on the fly. (I will use AudioKit) --> that's the part I m not confident. 
   Would I be able to send the audio buffer to Audiokit (which would process it) and give back the processed audio to AVPlayer like if it was the original AVPlayer audio part?

3) Save a final file with video and audio modified --> easy part with AVFundation
```

Please, ask for any information ;)

Comment: Just to make sure you are recording a video, but want to alter the audio samples? if so you can use AVCaptureVideoDataOutput with AVCaptureAudioDataOutput, this will give you CMSample's of audio which you can put through whatever process you like in a syncronous queue which will be outputted through an AVAssetWriter

Comment: It is almost that. The audio processing needs to be done after the recording, as users would choose which audio effect to apply to final video. Would be cool to have a equivalent to AVCaptureAudioDataOutput but at a AVPlayer level (Audiokit does supply this but without video support)

Comment: you can you AVAssetReader I think, that also outputs Samples of an already recorded file

Comment: OK thxs. I will dive into this next week, following up this first lead. I will come back to ask more and/or to post my work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of one fairly simple way to do this.

Basically you just need to open your video file in an AKPlayer instance. Then, you mute your video audio. Now, you have the video audio in AudioKit. It's pretty simple to lock the video and audio together using a common clock. Pseudo-code of the flow:

```
// This will represent a common clock using the host time
var audioClock = CMClockGetHostTimeClock()

// your video player
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer( url: videoURL )
videoPlayer.masterClock = audioClock
videoPlayer.automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling = false

....

var audioPlayer: AKPlayer?

// your video-audio player
if let player = try? AKPlayer(url: videoURL) {
    audioPlayer = player
}

func schedulePlayback(videoTime: TimeInterval, audioTime: TimeInterval, hostTime: UInt64 ) {
    audioPlay( audioTime, hostTime: hostTime )
    videoPlay(at: 0, hostTime: hostTime)
}


func audioPlay(at time: TimeInterval = 0, hostTime: UInt64 = 0) {
    audioPlayer.play(when: time, hostTime: hostTime)    
}

func videoPlay(at time: TimeInterval = 0, hostTime: UInt64 = 0 ) {
    let cmHostTime = CMClockMakeHostTimeFromSystemUnits(hostTime)
    let cmVTime = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(time, 1000000)
    let futureTime = CMTimeAdd(cmHostTime, cmVTime)
    videoPlayer.setRate(1, time: kCMTimeInvalid, atHostTime: futureTime)
}
```

You can connect the player up to any AudioKit processing chain in the normal way.

When you want to export your audio, run an AKNodeRecorder on the final output processing chain. Record this to file, then merge your audio into your video. I'm not sure if the AudioKit offline processing that is being worked on is ready yet, so you may need to play the audio in real time to capture the processing output.

Comment: Thanks you Ryan. If if I got it right, I would have a standard AVPlayer for the video (muted), a AKAudioPlayer for playing and processing audio. I have to to check how to synchronize players, cool if it's pretty simple then! :P (I don't understand why you say "but it sounds like they aren't locked anyway", Can you elaborate this? About the offline rendering (which would be so appreciated for my case), the following post says that Audiokit can do it without iOS 11, but it contrast with last audiokit release note. https://stackoverflow.com/q/45799686/6731119

Comment: I'll edit my answer to show how to lock an AVPlayer and AKAudioPlayers to a common clock.

Comment: @RyanFrancesconi Is AKPlayer still available? Looks like it was removed from AudioKit.

Comment: I don't know - they might of made a different name now. You can write your own player though using AVAudioPlayer