# Sync AVPlayer video with an audio file played with AVAudioPlayerNode

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudioengine

I have an `AVPlayer` instance that plays a locally stored file containing both video and audio tracks.

While playing (or just before playing the file) I would like to add some audio effects using `AVAudioEngine`.

By looking around I did not find a correlation between `AVAudioEngine` and `AVPlayer` so my question is there a way to make them work together?

I have read an answer mentioning `MTAudioProcessingTap` and will try using it although it seems to require more work (no problem with that but if there is a higher cleaner api for this I would like to use it)

Another solution I tried is muting the AVPlayer audio and play the audio using `AVAudioPlayerNode` (which works with `AVAudioEngine`). This works but I need them to be in sync (`AVPlayer` and the `AVAudioPlayerNode`). Is there a way to do that incase the above is not possible

Comment: See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47475499/ios-process-audio-from-avplayer-video-track/47482663#47482663