# iOS: How to intercept and manipulate bytes in AVPlayer

Tags: ios, swift, encryption, avfoundation, avplayer

Is there a way to intercept byte data and perform a XOR operation to each byte prior to playing audio in AVPlayer?

I'm building an audio streaming app and use a little script written in C to add a simple layer of encryption to the MP3 files. In Android it gets decoded in real time like this:

```
@Override
public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws FileDataSourceException {
        // ...
        if (readLength == 1 && offset >= 1 && offset <= 123) {
            buffer[offset] = (byte)(buffer[offset] ^ 11);
        }

        return bytesRead;
    }
}
```

As you can see above reversing the XOR encryption is fairly easy in Android as I use ExoPlayer and override the read() method in its datasource classes.
Is there any chance to perform the same thing using AVPlayer with Swift?

Here's a flowchart of the whole idea:

[AVPlayer encryption flowchart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/paMBD.jpg)

Thank you.

Comment: So the main thing you want is to encrypt a decrypted file on the fly?

Comment: The other way around. The app needs to decrypt the mp3 which has been encrypted offline using the little C script and it needs to do this on the fly while streaming it from https.

Comment: I guess you can use AVAudioEngine manual rendering feature to get buffers manipulate and renderToFile again. https://stackoverflow.com/a/45800100/5923606

Comment: Are you bound to use `AVAudioPlayer`? From a first look, `AudioToolbox` seems to be suitable for your use case. You can specify your own callback function to be used when calling `AudioFileStreamParseBytes(_:_:_:_:)`. Documentation can be found here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/audiotoolbox/audio_file_stream_services

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll want to use `MTAudioProcessingTap` for this, which is a property of `AVPlayer`'s  `AVAudioMix`. In your tap process callback, use `MTAudioProcessingTapGetSourceAudio` to grab your buffers. Once you have your buffer reference you can xor the data.

There's some boilerplate needed to get the `AVAudioMix` and `MTAudioProcessingTap` setup properly. The sample code that Apple has is pretty old, but still should work.
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/AudioTapProcessor/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40012324

Also note that it will be easier to do this in Objective C, for several reasons. The interop with your C file will be easier, and it is much more straightforward reading/writing to the buffer in Objc. It will also run faster than in swift. If you are interested to seeing what this would look like in swift, there is a sample project here:
https://github.com/gchilds/MTAudioProcessingTap-in-Swift

Comment: Is there an counterpart for video?

Comment: @mufumade, the closest thing would be `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` its not completely analogous, but probably the closest thing to a counterpart.